# How to detect mouse wheel tilt?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

To detect **rotation** of the mouse wheel in .NET/WinForms, I can override `OnMouseWheel`. **Clicking** can be detected by overriding `OnMouseDown` (it's just the `Middle` button). But how do I detect **tilting** of the wheel (tilt to the left/right for horizontal scrolling)? Neither `OnMouseWheel`, not `OnMouseDown` is being called when I tilt the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Covered [here](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/07/27/mouse-tilt-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-in-c/); in short, you need to handle the windows message manually (at it isn't handled directly in .NET - code is from the linked article):

> ```
>     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
>     {
>         base.WndProc(ref m);
>         if (m.HWnd != this.Handle)
>         {
>             return;
>         }
>         switch (m.Msg)
>         {
>             case Win32Messages.WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
>                 FireMouseHWheel(m.WParam, m.LParam);
>                 m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
>                 break;
>             default:
>                 break; 
>         }
>     }
>     ...
>     abstract class Win32Messages
>     {
>         public const int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;//discovered via Spy++
>     }
> ```

Comment: This works fine when your window has a horizontal scrollbar, but not otherwise. Just a note for people (like me 8-) who might want to abuse the tilt buttons for something other than horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I'm not getting any messages to my app from tilting the mouse wheel, but other apps are. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've posted this as a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092500/why-isnt-my-app-getting-mouse-wheel-tilt-messages

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [article](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/07/27/mouse-tilt-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-in-c/), if you have the IntelliPoint drivers, you will get [WM_MOUSEHWHEEL](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645614.aspx) messages.